# Google Analytics breaks emitted links in Angular.js project

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

In our Angular.js project, when emitting localized content I face a problem, that is, in case there are local <a href=>-s in the localized HTML strings, google analytics breaks them.

In particular, it changes

```
<a href="https://my-site.com/#!/path/to/somewhere">
```

into something like

```
<a href="https://my-site.com/?_ga=1.42271222.21175886562.1384128808#!/path/to/somewhere">
```

right at the moment I click the link (with either mouse button). When inspecting the DOM, I can see that the links I haven't yet touched are perfectly valid, while the link I right-clicked to select the "Inspect" popup menu item is broken in a way mentioned above.

UPD: The problem is solved.
Solution: use relative links whenever possible. If you are debugging your site, its address differs from the real one, so an absolute link to the real site address will be (obviously) considered cross-domain in the debug version.

In particular, the above link

```
<a href="https://my-site.com/#!/path/to/somewhere">
```

should have been changed to

```
<a href="/#!/path/to/somewhere">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like you are using cross domain tracking with GA ([_ga is the parameter that is used when "linking" domains](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain#linkerparam), it carries over the client id). Are there any decorators/autolinking functions enabled in the ga code ? I think Gas autolinking functions would not recognize the anchor as part of the url path and insert the linking parameter in between the domain and the anchor.

If you need cross domain tracking you could try not to use automatic linking and instead retrieve the client id manually and append it to the end of the url.

If you are not using cross domain tracking you should post your analytics-related code, there might be something misconfigured.

Comment: True, the problem was caused by the GA attempting to apply its cross-domain tracking logic to my links. The only thing that confused me was the fact that all the links were supposed to lead to our own site, no cross-domain destinations at all. After a little research, it turned out that there were some absolute links in the emitter code, and of course, when debugging locally, the site address is localhost:%port%/, so a link to my-site.com is considered cross-domain.